# css and javascript to show figcaption of image when clicked

Tags: javascript, css

i am having some trouble configuring my javascript with my css so that when an image is clicked a little caption bar will appear with icons in it. Currently when i hover over the image the caption bar appears but i want to change this so that it will be usable for users on tablets where they have to touch and don't have the hover feature.

**View page**

```
<figure>
    <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" 
             data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}" />
    <figcaption> 
        <a title="Email" id="emailIcon" class="icon-envelope icon-white" 
                   data-bind="attr:{'href':'mailto:' + Email()}"></a>
        <a title="Profile" id="profileIcon" class="icon-user icon-white"></a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure, figcaption {
    display: block;
}

 figure {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;
    width:158px;
    height:158px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1px;
}

 figure figcaption {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    opacity: .75;
    margin-bottom:-115px;       
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-property: margin-bottom;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-property: margin-bottom;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
}

 figure.open figcaption {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

 figcaption {
    width:160px;
    height:25px;
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**Javascript**  Not sure if there is a way to do it with just css or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.views.Roster.GetRoster('@url');
        $('figure').on('click', function (event) {
            $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('open'); 
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: In the CSS snippet you attached `open` class is used nowhere. Have you posted everything?

Comment: @rr- you mean the Javascript? i just added that but didn't really know how to properly connect or create the process for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great idea to just toggle a class and leave the visible elements to CSS.

```
$('figure').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('open'); 
});
```

In that case, style your figcaption the way you want it to look and then add:

```
figcaption { display: none; }
.open figcaption { display: block; }
```

This way, when the figcaption is hidden by default but when you click the target and the javascript adds the class "open" the figcaption will be visible.  You certainly don't have to have it display block, it could be most anything other than "none."

Comment: unfortunately it is still not working - not sure what could be causing it not work

Comment: i have my javascript in another file so i am using `event`

Comment: could you provide a link for more context?  Can you see the class toggling on click in the browser console?  Are there other javascript calls that are working?  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: This should be working.  When I copy all your content to jsFiddle the action works.  (http://jsfiddle.net/M8n6p/) So this is probably a problem with your javascript executing.

Comment: I placed the snippet of javascript that i have for the toggle in same javascript file that i am using to display my users on the page(getting the information) so the file is being called and is working. In the console i see the `$('figure')...` and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: i could try placing this piece of javascript into the view page itself and test it out i will post my scripts section for it.

Comment: here is what i did in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azchj/ i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: In this example, don't forget to add the context in the side of the fiddle page:  You need to include jQuery and set where it is showing up.  HTML markup in the JS box is redundant and the function call before the click event is referencing a null object, I'm guessing because it is missing something that comes before.  When you remove these, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/azchj/.  I would suggest adding some console calls to see if these functions are even being triggered: console.log("is this working?").

Comment: is the jsfiddle link you just provided supposed to be working?

Comment: Yup, but i guess the changes weren't saved.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/azchj/3/  Point being: the problem isn't the javascript code, CSS, or HTML.  The problem is that this JS isn't being properly called.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help i will look into the calling issue and hopefully get it resolved.

Comment: If i wanted to add `onready` so that i could wait for all the javascripts are loaded - how can i go about doing that with what i have?

Comment: Are you making any AJAX calls?  If not, you should be able to just place your event at the end of the last page of .js files and it should be executed last.  I can't say for certain without seeing the file.

Comment: Thanks again but i posted a new question and got it taken care of by `$(window).on("load", function() {`

Answer (score 1):

If this code

```
figure:hover figcaption {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

is showing the figcaption and you are putting `open` class to the `figure` when you want to show it, you can use:

```
figure:hover figcaption, figure.open figcaption {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i made the changes and now it the caption doesn't show on hover which is what i want but when i click on the image it is not showing either-yet

Comment: forgot to add the open as a class in the figure tag. but now it is a static view that shows on page load - how can i change it so it will show once the image is clicked?

Comment: @Amina I don't understand you. The `open` class should be only put with javascript and the `click` event, why do you said that you *forgot to add the open as a class in the figure tag*?

Comment: so my image in my `figure` tag - when i click it i want the `figcaption` tag to appear.

Comment: @Amina But what is it your problem now? It should work now, should't it? Did you change anything else of the current layout?

Comment: don't i need to add `class="open"` in my view? when i add it to my `figure` tag it is static on the page so it shows the caption on page load rather than waiting for a click.

Comment: No, you don't need it. You have an event `click` that will do it for you (that's the reason of you javascript code :D)

Comment: sorry i missed that i am not that savvy with javascript. So i removed it but still it is not showing when i click

Comment: @Amina Did you have any javascript error showing with Firebug (or similar)?

Comment: not it is showing fine no errors. do you think if i list all my css references where figure and figcaption are used might help clear up the problem. maybe i am overlooking something.